# Converting numbers using php

Tags: php

How to convert non-integrated numbers like this: 415.822948 to be integrated exactly like: 415 using PHP?

Comment: How are you storing these numbers? In a variable??

Comment: `echo round(rand(n, N), 0); `

Comment: i use ffprobe to get seconds of video in string

Comment: @executable floor() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function for this.

Here's an example:

```
echo intval(415.822948);
```

This will output: `415`

Comment: I would be nice if you had shown an example rather than just posting a link only answer, which are not really popular on SO

Comment: it worked, Thank you <3

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added an example to the answer.